# How to call Swift mailer in yii2 with console controller?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
Yii::$app
          ->mailer
          ->compose(
              ['html' => 'remainder-html', 'text' => 'remainder-text'],
              ['user' => $user,'interview'=>$interview]
          )
          ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
          ->setTo($user->email)
          ->setSubject('Contact Request From ' . $model->name)
          ->send();
```

Above is the code I have used in console/controller for advanced app in yii2. Rest of things are working only the mail is not working. Same code work when placed in backend/frontend controller. Following is the error.

> PHP User Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Call to
>   undefined method compose'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii2 Applications use a different configuration file for console and web.

All you need to do is configure the 'mailer' component in your console configuration file. If you are using the Basic Application Template, this is the 'config/console.php'.